# Android tts voice name format

Tags: android, text-to-speech

The Android TextToSpeech component return the list of available voices through the API getVoices(). This API return a list of Voice objects. A Voice object have the method getName() but the returned name is something of incomprehensible, something like "ja-jp-x-jac-network" and so on. It looks like information coded in some way but I didn't find info in android developer web site. Someone have more info or can point me to a document explaining this format?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the String returned by getName() is implemented by the particular TTS Engine that is in use by your tts -- Google or Samsung, etc.  They all do it differently.

There is no requirement on them from the Android framework other than to supply a unique string.